# How to navigate google map in android tv app using remote d-pad?

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, television, d-pad

I already have a mobile map application so I know all basic map functionalities. Now I want to build a TV version of it but I didn't know how to move/pan/drag map in Android TV using dpad..

I've tried `OnFocusListener`, `OnKeyListener`/`DispatchKeyEvent` method with Map Gestures Controls.

```
switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
    // Do something when the up button is pressed
      break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
    // Do something when the down button is pressed
      break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
    // Do something when the left button is pressed
      break;
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
      // Do something when the right button is pressed
      break;
    default:
      return false;
}
```

Comment: Maybe changing the current center of the map when pressing the direction keypads should work?

Comment: At now, I am moving the map by extracting the map coordinates (lat, lng) from the screen point (x,y) but this method is not sufficient, not getting the same results as I get from mobile screen touch.

Comment: Have you tried adding and subtracting to the lat or lng when pressing the arrow pads?

Comment: Actually doing same thing but I update points value not lat/lng. see map projection method https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/reference/com/google/android/libraries/maps/Projection